# How to implement scrollable tab bar in Chrome like in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome

When there are too many tabs in Chrome, the tabs become microscopic. I can not see the tab title. I have tried a lot of extensions, but nothing provided a good solution.

How can I make the Chrome tab bar scrollable like Firefox?

Comment: I do not use Chrome for that specific reason. I use Vivaldi, a chrome based browser. You can simply stack tabs into a group, so they become 1 tab. My advice, switch to another browser if this is a problem. Keep in mind, too many tabs consume a lot of memory and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 8):

Scrollable tabs in Chrome are a long-running request to be found in
[UI: tab overflow](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=188)
dating from 2008 !!

A hidden setting has existed called *Stacked Tabs*,
described [here](https://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-hidden-secret-stacked-tabs-feature-in-google-chrome/),
but I cannot find it anymore in my current Chrome version.

It is said that it can be re-enabled again by adding to the Chrome command-line
the parameter of `--force-stacked-tab-strip-layout`,
but there are other reports that say it is only going to only be available
on mobile devices. It certainly doesn't work on my desktop Chrome.

It seems like there is no other solution, and even this one is going out
or already gone. Chrome developers detest tab scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Morons. I way prefer tab-scrolling so I can see some of the text to tell which tab is which. Google are TERRIBLE at making user-facing applications and tools.

Answer (score 4):

Since at least April of 2019, the flag `scrollable-tabstrip` is present in Chrome, but unfortunately enabling that flag does nothing as of yet. I couldn't dig up any info on when this feature could start working, but I hope this happens soon.

As for extensions, I don't believe Chrome allows for extensions to interact with the layout of the tabstrip. The good ol' tab managers can list your tabs (perhaps in multiple Chrome windows) as a drop-down list, and allow you to switch, kill or swap tabs. What I would actually find more convenient is a floating tab-strip attached to the bottom of each webpage (which would emulate Chrome's tabstrip, but be scrollable). That's definitely doable, and I believe it could be done without compromising performance.

Answer (score 3):

I waited it from 2008 and this feature is finally here!

- For now it works only in latest version of **Chrome Canary**.
- Load chrome://settings/help to
  check the version and if updates are available. The feature is
  available in version 88.0.4284.0.
- List item chrome://flags/#scrollable-tabstrip in the browser's address bar.
- Set the Scrollable TabStrip experiment to Enabled using the menu on its right. Click on relaunch to restart the browser.

Comment: I just found out about this, what with Firefox' Proton fiasco (I tried Firefox Color to make the current tab stand out, but that insists on changing *all* color and I'm not in the mood of correcting the mess).  So, I searched (googled, natch) for scrollable tab bar again, and… now I'm back to Chrome.  I *do* hope this flag becomes official.

Comment: Thanks! this is definitely what I was looking for!